# Usecase dependency to other usecase in Clean Architecture

Tags: python, dependency-injection, clean-architecture

I'm using **Clean Architecture** in my `python` project. I have two `usecase` one is `TranslationUseCase` and second is `AudioUsecase`. **TranslaionUseCase** depend on **AudioUsecase**

**TranslationUseCase**

```
class TranslationUseCase:
   def __init(self, trans_repo):
       self.trans_repo = trans_repo


   def find_translation(self, also_audio=False):
       if also_audio:
          audio_factory = AudioFactory.find_audio()
          audio = audio_factory.find_by_id(123)

       translation = trans_repo.find_by_id(123)
       # .... Other Code
```

**AudioUseCase**

```
class AudioUseCase:
     def __init(self, audio_repo):
        self.audio_repo = audio_repo


     def find_by_id(self, id):
         return self.audio_repo.find_by_id(id)
```

**TranslationFactory**

```
 class TranslationFactory:

    @classmethod
    def find_translation(cls):
        trans_repo = TranslationRepo()
        return TranslationUseCase(trans_repo)
```

**AudioFactory**

```
 class AudioFactory:

    @classmethod
    def find_audio(cls):
        audio_repo = AudioRepo()
        return AudioUseCase(audio_repo)
```

I'm using this way and everything is working fine I don't know this is a correct way or not. Because there is problem when I write test, in tests there is totally different `repos` that's why I create the different `factories` for them. `TestTranslationFactory` and `TestAudioFactory` This create issue when I try to write test for `TranslationUseCase` because it hardcoded the `AudioFactory` What is the possible and best solution for this.

**One solution which is in my mind is pass `audio_factory` in `TranslationUsecase` constructor to remove the dependency**

Comment: Your question is too broad, however, I think your proposed solution is correct and is called "dependency injection". The alternative would be to make `audio` a parameter of `TranslationUseCase.find_translation()` so instead of the boolean, you let the caller decide which audio they want to use. The dependency then moves to the caller. The main difference is on if you want TranslationUseCase to be used with only one audio factory, or with many.